# xml data in php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I'm a php and javascript newbie so don't be mad.
Ok so i want to get xml file from another server and then extract only one data(number) and put it in javascript variable so i can calculate with it.

I have this code that gets xml file fine, and i get $result variable with data that i need, but i can't save that data in javascript variable.
The reason i need this number in javascript is because all of calculations are coded in javascript.

this is php code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
'http://www.pbz.hr/Downloads/PBZteclist.xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);

echo($xml);

curl_close($ch); 

$xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$node = $xmlObject->children();
$result =   $node[0]->Currency[12]->BuyRateForeign;
echo("<br />");
echo("<br />");
echo $result;
?>
```

I need data from EUR7,480000

That number 7,480000 is all i need to extract and save in javascript variable.

Maybe the way i'm doing this isn't right, but i have tryied everything. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest grabbing the value using an xpath, in case the order changes up.
If you want to use as a string, wrap it in quotes. If you are using it in calculations you might need to strip out the commas etc...

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
'http://www.pbz.hr/Downloads/PBZteclist.xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//echo($xml);

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$result = $sxe->xpath("//Currency[@Code='978']");
$BRF = $result[0]->BuyRateForeign;
?>
<script>
  var bfr_string = '<?= $BRF?>'; //string
  var bfr_number = <?= str_replace(',','.',$BRF)?>; //number
</script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Everithing works great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't intend to do this with Ajax:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.pbz.hr/Downloads/PBZteclist.xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);

echo($xml);

curl_close($ch);

$xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$node = $xmlObject->children();
$result =   $node[0]->Currency[12]->BuyRateForeign;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rate = '<?php echo $result; ?>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to be set in javascript on page load, you can use php to echo a javascript string to initiate a variable.

In PHP:

```
<script>
<?php echo "var data = ".$result; ?>
</script>
```

If you are getting the data asynchronously you will have to use javascript AJAX to call a PHP page that outputs your data in some kind of format (JSON), or just a single string value.